# In Azure, how to clone a repo that uses git-lfs repo in a different server?

Tags: git, azure, azure-pipelines, git-lfs

I have a repository that contains some files and a directory where I use git-lfs to store big files in another repository outside the domain of the first one. When I want to retrieve my project, I clone the first repository and then it's asked me the credentials for the second repository, so far so good.

The problem is, when I'm in Azure, trying to clone my repository, I don't see in the log the asking for the second repository credentials, I only see

```
[5e71564651651654646516465164613211] LFS object not found: [404] LFS object not found
```

In my pipeline, It's checked the "checkout submodules" and "checkout files from LFS". When I uncheck those, my pipeline fetches the pointer for those big files, not the files themselves.

I think that the Azure is looking on the first repo for the git-lfs files, but I'm not sure. Thus, I can't find in Azure interface where to put the credentials for the second repository.

My question is: Is it possible to clone my repo using another server as git-lfs repository when you are using Azure pipeline? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new Branch, cloned it with the flags "checkout submodules" and "checkout files from LFS" checked, then I added a ssh step in my pipeline Azure to git checkout the branch that contains the git-lfs files.

I believe that git-lfs files are only fetched correctly when you checkout, not when you clone the repository.

Comment: Hi @Gustavo Nóbrega,

Thanks for sharing the answer.
Looks like, you have find a way to checkout the LFS files now, right? If so, you can mark this answer as the solution of this ticket. This may be helpful to other people who have the similar questions when they are looking for a solution.

In addition, you also can try the command **`git clone <repo_URL> -b <BRANCH_NAME>`** in the ssh step of your pipeline. You can use this command to only clone the branch that contains LFS files from remote and checkout it on the local.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like as this:

1. Don't check "checkout files from LFS" in the get source settings of the pipeline.
2. Add a step in the pipeline to execute the **git lfs clone** command to checkout files from LFS. You can provide the credentials in the command.
   For example:

- **HTTPS**

```
git lfs clone https://<USERNAME>:<PAT>@<service_domain>/<repo_path>
```

- **SSH**

```
git lfs clone git@ssh.<service_domain>:v3/<repo_path>
```

Comment: Using Azure Devops here. SSH protocol doesn't work for me. Don't know why but always get an error. Only HTTPS seems works for me.